# Speed-up tensorflowjs model

Tags: tensorflow, mxnet, onnx, tensorflowjs-converter

I trained a model using [mxnet](https://mxnet.apache.org/) framework. The inference time for the model is ~ 9 milliseconds.
The model mainly consists of conv layers and uses depthwise separable convolution.

I want to run that model in browser. I converted the model to ONNX format then from

ONNX -> tensorflow -> tensorflowjs.

The inference time for tensorflowjs model ~129 milliseconds.

Any suggestion to improve the performance for the model?

I have also tried [ONNXJS](https://github.com/Microsoft/onnxjs) but it seems it still has few [bugs](https://github.com/Microsoft/onnxjs/issues/94).

Comment: It seems while converting the model from mxnet to ONNX -> Tensorflow, the num_group parameter for conv layers in mxnet was not considered correctly. I ran the tensorflow model and it took ~90 milliseconds. I will try to build and train the model using Keras and check if there will be any enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

Re-architecting would be a possibility since you're dealing with 129ms latency. You would have time to send images to an endpoint (EC2, or SageMaker + API Gateway) running a performant inference server.

Vishaal

Comment: Yes, I saw mxnet.js but it seems outdated and the last commit is years ago.

Comment: Looking into it, you're correct, it's not actively maintained. Edited my answer to remove MXNet.js as an option.